# How do you find $\frac{dH}{dt}$ where, $H(x,y)=\sin(3x-y), x^3+2y=2t^3, x-y^2=t^2+3t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do you find $\frac{dH}{dt}$ where,

$$H(x,y)=\sin(3x-y), x^3+2y=2t^3, x-y^2=t^2+3t$$

I think I'm supposed to use the multivariable chain rule,

$$\frac{dH}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=3\cos(3x-y), \frac{\partial H}{\partial y}=-\cos(3x-y)$$

So factoring out $cos(3x-y)$ I have,

$$\frac{dH}{dt}=\cos(3x-y)[3\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{dy}{dt}]$$

The problem is that I have no idea how to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ from the above equations.

The correct answer is $$\frac{dH}{dt}=\frac{36t^2y+12t+9x^2-6t^2+6x^2t+18}{6x^2y+2}\,\cos(3x-y)$$

Comment: Use implicit differentiation. If you differentiate your equations with respect to $t$, then you'll end up with a 2 variables linear system of equations

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin I've tried doing that. Say I implicitly differentiate w.r.t. x, I got this $(3x^2)\frac{dx}{dt}=6t^2$ in the first equation and $\frac{dx}{dt}=2t+3$ in the second equation. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: @YipJungHon that's wrong way to differentiate them. Look at Ishams answer

Answer (score 1):

Just differentiate wrt to $t$
$$
\begin{cases}
 x^3+2y=2t^3 \\
 x-y^2=t^2+3t
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\implies 
\begin{cases}
3x^2x'+2y'=6t^2 \\
 x'-2yy'=2t+3
\end{cases}
$$

where $x'=\frac {dx}{dt}$ and  $y'=\frac {dy}{dt}$

Solve the system to express $x'$ and $y'$ as function of $x,y$